# How to ask 5 different numbers and then answer it?

Tags: java, random

```
import java.util.*;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int random = (int)(Math.random() * 3 + 1);

        //to see what number to guess
        System.out.println(random);

        int score = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
        String num = input.nextLine();
        int count = 0;

        while (count <= 5) {
            if (random == 1) {
                if (num.equals("one")) {
                    System.out.println("correct");
                    score++;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("Wrong!");
                }
            }
            else if (random == 2) {
                if (num.equals("two")) {
                    System.out.println("correct");
                    score++;
                }
                else {

                    System.out.print("Wrong!");
                }
            }
            else {
                if (num.equals("three")) {
                    System.out.println("correct");
                    score++;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("Wrong!");
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(score);
    }
}
```

How do I make it that will ask 5 different random numbers ?.

After every good guess, the score should be incremented by 1.

After every guess (good or bad), it should proceed to another random number?

Comment: you need an array for the 5 numbers, which must be generated in a range between a and b, then compare the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange that you allocate a `Random` class to not use it.

You should use it, and write `rand.nextInt(3 + 1)` (exclusive, thus the +1) rather than `(int)(Math.random() * 3 + 1)`.

Your while loop can be simplified by a for loop: `for (int count = 0; count < 5; ++count)`. Beware, initializing your variable to **`0`** and going to **`<= 5`** will result to **6** iterations, not 5.

You do not need to create an array of 5 numbers in your case, you can simply generate a new random number for each guess, inside your loop.

You could also reduce redundancy in your code with a map like `1 to "one", 2 to "two", etc.`

In the end, I would write it like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int score = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        HashMap<Integer, String> intToString = new HashMap<>();

        intToString.put(1, "one");
        intToString.put(2, "two");
        intToString.put(3, "three");

        for (int count = 0; count < 5; ++count) {
            // "nextInt" is exclusive! Doing +1 converts [0;2] to [1;3]
            int random = rand.nextInt(3 + 1);

            // To see what number to guess
            System.out.println(random);

            String num = input.nextLine();

            // Get the string representation
            String response = intToString.get(random);

            if (num.equals(response)) {
                System.out.println("correct");
                ++score;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong!");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(score);
    }
}
```

If you are using Java 1.7+, you can use `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` rather than `Random`. [Related post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/363692/7709086).

Answer (score 0):

To Read 5 numbers from the user, write a code something like below

```
public Integer [] read5NumbersFromConsole(Scanner input){
    Integer [] inputNumber = new Integer [5];   
  for(int i =0; i< 5; i++){
     System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
        inputNumber[i] = input.nextInt();

   }
return inputNumber;
}
```

The rest I left it for you to implement...